# Creating an Evaluation Query for 3 months, 6 months and 12 months

Tags: sql

I am in need of getting correct query for gathering records based on their hire_date and their evaluations that occurs with these parameters:

- 3 months
- 6 months
- 12 months

from system_date.

The way the report will work is collecting employees that have evaluations due dates between 30 days past and 90 days after the current system_date.

Here is the tricky part: If the hire_date is greater than 1 year from system_date than only 12 month evaluations will exist.  If their current assignment changes, as in their job, they revert back to 3, 6 and 12 months evaluations, but will ultimately end up being back in 12 months evaluations.

Let me know if you need more clarification.

**Flow chart**:

[image: flow-chart]

Comment: It does not make sense to me. Could you please improve your question? If you add examples and also more info regarding the _tricky part_, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Zanon.  I'll provide some examples:

Comment: Let's say for instance a person has a hire_date of June 15, 2014.  Since it is their first year, they would be subject to a 3, 6 and 12 month evaluation.

Comment: After their first year, they no longer have a 3 or 6 month evaluation; they only have a 12 month evaluation.  The range that the report should grab is anyone who falls within 1 month of the sysdate and 3 months (90) days upcoming from sysdate.  If any individuals 3, 6 or 12 month evaluation dates fall within the 30 - sysdate - 90 days, then their record would be shown, otherwise, they do not meet the criteria yet.  Eventually, everyone will have the annual evaluation.    An example of the 30 - sysdate - 90 would be August 24, 2014 - September 24, 2014 - December 24, 2014.  Hope that helps?

Comment: It is easier to understand now. You've said "90 days prior" in your question and "90 days after" in your comment. "After" makes sense. I believe that you have to edit your question and add more info regarding your tables, what you've already tried and which database you are using, so it will be easier for others to help you. Also, sqlfiddle.com is a good tool for providing sample data.

Comment: Sorry for the inconsistent usage of the 90 days.  Thanks for the tip on sqlfiddle.com. Is there a way I can post a flow chart on here?  I guess I need 10 reputation to post images?  Makes showing somewhat difficult.

Comment: I've added the flow chart to help visualize what the concept of the sql logic will be executing.  The Assign Str = hire_date of the employee.

Answer (score 1):

As I don't know your tables or which database you are using, I've created the following sample solution using MS SQL Server. I've declared variables, a CTE (common table expression) and created a function for readability, but you can easily substitute them.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab730/2)

First, I've considered that you have a simple `Employees` table with the `hire_date` and `last_assignment_change`.

I've inserted some sample data for testing:

**Employees**

```
| ID |  NAME |  HIRE_DATE | LAST_ASSIGNMENT_CHANGE | 
|----|-------|------------|------------------------|
|  1 | Alice | 2012-07-15 |                 (null) | 
|  2 |   Bob | 2013-12-02 |                 (null) |
|  3 | Carol | 2014-01-13 |                 (null) |
|  4 |  Dave | 2014-01-13 |             2014-08-28 |
|  5 |   Eve | 2014-03-15 |                 (null) |
|  6 | Frank | 2014-06-15 |                 (null) |
|  7 |  Gina | 2014-09-15 |                 (null) |
```

So, we have:

```
Today = 2014-09-25  
Filter dates between 2014-08-25 and 2014-12-25

Alice: next evaluation = 2014-07-15 -> do not show
Bob:   next evaluation = 2014-12-02 -> show
Carol: next evaluation = 2015-01-13 -> do not show
Dave:  next evaluation = 2014-11-28 -> show
Eve:   next evaluation = 2014-09-15 -> show
Frank: next evaluation = 2014-09-15 -> show
Gina:  next evaluation = 2014-12-15 -> show
```

Next, I've created a function to simplify the CAST to DATE used in end of the query:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_CastDate
                 ( @year int, @month int, @day int )
RETURNS date
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN
    CAST(
        CAST(@year AS VARCHAR(4)) +
        RIGHT('0' + CAST(@month AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
        RIGHT('0' + CAST(@day AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) 
     AS DATE)
END
GO
```

Finally, the query to filter by the evaluation dates:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE
    @today date, 
    @last_month date,
    @next_three_months date    

  SET @today = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
  SET @last_month = DATEADD(month, -1, @today)
  SET @next_three_months = DATEADD(month, 3, @today)

  ;WITH employees_cte AS
  (
    SELECT
      id,
      name,
      COALESCE(last_assignment_change, hire_date) AS assignment_date -- if last_assignment_change is null, use hire_date
    FROM
      employees
  )
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    employees_cte
  WHERE
    DATEADD(month, 3, assignment_date) BETWEEN @last_month AND @next_three_months -- Evaluation = 3 months
    OR
    DATEADD(month, 6, assignment_date) BETWEEN @last_month AND @next_three_months -- Evaluation = 6 months
    OR
    DATEADD(month, 12, assignment_date) BETWEEN @last_month AND @next_three_months -- Evaluation = 12 months
    OR
    (DATEDIFF(day, assignment_date, @next_three_months) < 365 -- Evaluation = annual
      AND
         (dbo.fn_CastDate(YEAR(@last_month), MONTH(assignment_date), DAY(assignment_date)) -- test with YEAR(@last_month)
               BETWEEN @last_month AND @next_three_months
           OR

          dbo.fn_CastDate(YEAR(@next_three_months), MONTH(assignment_date), DAY(assignment_date)) -- test with YEAR(@next_three_months)
               BETWEEN @last_month AND @next_three_months)
    )

END
```

**Output:**

```
| ID |  NAME | ASSIGNMENT_DATE |
|----|-------|-----------------|
|  2 |   Bob |      2013-12-02 |
|  4 |  Dave |      2014-08-28 |
|  5 |   Eve |      2014-03-15 |
|  6 | Frank |      2014-06-15 |
|  7 |  Gina |      2014-09-15 |
```

**Note:** the function CastDate will fail if you try to convert a date like `2012-02-29` (Leap Year) to `2014-02-29` (not a Leap Year). To solve this, convert `February 29` to `February 28` before using the the CAST.

Comment: Zanon, this is great.  Works perfectly. This is exactly the logic I needed.  I'm adding additional fields, but can do that in the SELECT area.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

NB: I have assumed Oracle is the dbms given you are referring to sysdate.

It would be simpler for all concerned if there was a provided set of sample data and expected result.
However, using this data (derived from Zanon's hope you don't mind):

```
| ID |  NAME |  HIRE_DATE | ISCONTRACTOR | TERM_DATE |
|----|-------|------------|--------------|-----------|
|  1 | Alice | 2012-07-15 |            0 |    (null) |
|  2 |   Bob | 2013-12-02 |            0 |    (null) |
|  3 | Carol | 2014-01-13 |            1 |    (null) |
|  4 |  Dave | 2014-01-13 |            0 |    (null) |
|  5 |   Eve | 2014-03-15 |            0 |    (null) |
|  6 | Frank | 2014-06-15 |            0 |    (null) |
|  7 |  Gina | 2014-09-15 |            0 |    (null) |
```

and this query:

```
select
        id
      , name
      , to_char(hire_date,'yyyy-mm-dd') hire_date
      , to_char(anniversary,'yyyy-mm-dd') anniversary
      , case when evaldue = 3  then to_char(add_months(hire_date,3) ,'yyyy-mm-dd')
             when evaldue = 6  then to_char(add_months(hire_date,6) ,'yyyy-mm-dd')
             when evaldue = 9  then to_char(add_months(hire_date,9) ,'yyyy-mm-dd')
             when evaldue = 12 then to_char(anniversary,'yyyy-mm-dd') 
        end evaldue_date
      , evaldue
FROM (
      select
            employees.*
          , case
                 when add_months(hire_date,3)  > trunc(sysdate) then 3 
                 when add_months(hire_date,6)  > trunc(sysdate) then 6 
                 when add_months(hire_date,9)  > trunc(sysdate) then 9 
                 else 12 
            end evaldue
          , to_date(to_char(sysdate,'YYYY') || to_char(hire_date,'MMDD'),'YYYYMMDD') anniversary
      from employees
      where iscontractor = 0 -- i.e. only for employees
      and term_date IS NULL
      )
WHERE
        case when evaldue = 3  then add_months(hire_date,3)
             when evaldue = 6  then add_months(hire_date,6)
             when evaldue = 9  then add_months(hire_date,9)
             when evaldue = 12 then anniversary
        end between trunc(sysdate) - 30 and trunc(sysdate) + 90
ORDER BY
      evaldue_date ASC
    , evaldue ASC
;
```

This is the calculated result:

```
| ID |  NAME |  HIRE_DATE | ANNIVERSARY | EVALDUE_DATE | EVALDUE |
|----|-------|------------|-------------|--------------|---------|
|  4 |  Dave | 2014-01-13 |  2014-01-13 |   2014-10-13 |       9 |
|  2 |   Bob | 2013-12-02 |  2014-12-02 |   2014-12-02 |      12 |
|  7 |  Gina | 2014-09-15 |  2014-09-15 |   2014-12-15 |       3 |
|  6 | Frank | 2014-06-15 |  2014-06-15 |   2014-12-15 |       6 |
|  5 |   Eve | 2014-03-15 |  2014-03-15 |   2014-12-15 |       9 |
```

- based on hire_date an "evaldue" of 3,6 or 9 is calculated (i.e. which
  performance review is needed) if the hire_date is beyond 9 months the
  evaldue is 12.
- The anniversary of hire_date is also calculated for later reference
- using those prior calculations an evaldue_date is calculated
- then that calculated evaldue_date is compared to sysdate - 30 to sysdate + 90

  <kbd>[See this demonstrated at SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f5ef89/1)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, Used_By_Already!  I do not have a 9 month eval, but thanks for the logic.  Is the Anniversary column in your select statement the same as Hire_Date?

Comment: Is Anniversary = Hire_Date? No. Only in for the first year of employment. Anniversary has the year determined by sysdate like this: `to_date(to_char(sysdate,'YYYY')` then it adds the month and day of Hire_Date (so it is literally an anniversary - like a wedding anniversary)